# Agrupar Números con mayor frecuencia Tabla SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

Teniendo la tabla TblSorteos

```
------------------------------- 
nrosorteo |n1|n2|n3|
-------------------------
2000      |3 |20|18|
-------------------------------
2001      |21|18|11|
-------------------------------
2002      |11|20|18|
-------------------------------
2003      |3 |20|18|
```

Necesito saber cuáles números se han repetido más de una vez y en qué sorteo.

De ésta manera:

---

```
NUMEROS |cantidad|Sorteo             |
--------------------------------------------------
3       |  2     | 2000, 2003
-------------------------------------------------|
20      |  3     | 2000, 2002, 2003              |
-------------------------------------------------|
18      |  3     | 2000, 2002, 2003      |
-------------------------------------------------|
11      |  2     | 2001, 2002                    |
-------------------------------------------------|
```

Estoy tratando de hacerlo de ésta manera:

```
select NUMEROS,cantidad, Sorteo FROM(
SELECT (" "||n1||"-"||n2||"-"||n3||)AS 'NUMEROS', COUNT(*) cantidad,
GROUP_CONCAT(" "||nrosorteo)AS Sorteo from TblSorteos
GROUP BY NUMEROS HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Pero no me muestra nada. Algo estoy haciendo mal y no sé que es.

Si lo hago asi:

```
SELECT (n1||"-"||n2||"-"||n3) AS 'NUMEROS', COUNT(*) VECES,
GROUP_CONCAT(" "||nrosorteo)AS Sorteo
 
FROM TblSorteos
GROUP BY 1 HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY VECES DESC
```

Me muestra "sequencias" repetidas de los números.

No se en qué estoy fallando. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Los requisitos de tu propuesta plantean una duda: ¿la repetición de números se basa solamente en que hayan aparecido en diferentes sorteos o en que hayan aparecido en diferentes sorteos y además en la misma posición/columna?

De tu enunciado puede deducirse que basta la repetición en cualquier posición: "Necesito saber cuáles números se han repetido más de una vez y en qué sorteo". Sin embargo, de la tabla de salida que propones se deduce que los números deben repetirse en la misma posición, porque solamente señalas 3 ocurrencias del número 18 cuando en realidad ha aparecido en 4 sorteos.

Sin embargo, de la lógica habitual de este tipo de juegos de azar, cabe deducir que la posición u orden de extracción de los números no es relevante, así que este es el presupuesto de trabajo que utilizaré en esta solución.

En primer lugar, estas son las sentencias DDL-DML de SQLite para crear y llenar las tablas según tus datos, que puedes utilizar para resolver el problema y someter a prueba la solución:

```sql
-- Creación de la tabla
CREATE TABLE TblSorteos (
  nrosorteo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  n1 INTEGER,
  n2 INTEGER,
  n3 INTEGER
);

-- Inserción de los registros de sorteos
INSERT INTO TblSorteos (nrosorteo, n1, n2, n3) VALUES (2000, 3, 20, 18);
INSERT INTO TblSorteos (nrosorteo, n1, n2, n3) VALUES (2001, 21, 18, 11);
INSERT INTO TblSorteos (nrosorteo, n1, n2, n3) VALUES (2002, 11, 20, 18);
INSERT INTO TblSorteos (nrosorteo, n1, n2, n3) VALUES (2003, 3, 20, 18);
```

Y a continuación, la consulta que permite contar las repeticiones u ocurrencias en diferentes sorteos de cada número que se haya repetido más de una vez, agrupada por los números:

```sql
SELECT Numero, COUNT(*) AS Cantidad, GROUP_CONCAT(nrosorteo, ', ') AS Sorteo
FROM (
  SELECT n1 AS Numero, nrosorteo FROM TblSorteos
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n2 AS Numero, nrosorteo FROM TblSorteos
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n3 AS Numero, nrosorteo FROM TblSorteos
)
GROUP BY Numero
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY Cantidad DESC;
```

El bloque externo de la consulta utiliza la función COUNT para calcular el número de ocurrencias de cada grupo y la función GROUP_CONCAT concatena los años de sorteo empleando el delimitador de su segundo argumento. El SELECT interno o anidado, la parte más interesante, es una subconsulta donde se combinan mediante UNION ALL aplicado a tres consultas los números de los sorteos en una sola columna llamada `Numero`, asociándolos con el año (`nrosorteo`) de sorteo correspondiente.

Mediante GROUP BY se organizan los resultados por la columna Numero, la cláusula HAVING permite filtrar los resultados que no tengan más de 1 repetición y ORDER BY ordena la salida por la `Cantidad` de repeticiones o el criterio que prefieras.

Salida:

```swift
+--------+----------+------------------------+
| Numero | Cantidad |         Sorteo         |
+--------+----------+------------------------+
|     18 |        4 | 2001, 2000, 2002, 2003 |
|     20 |        3 |       2000, 2002, 2003 |
|     11 |        2 |             2002, 2001 |
|      3 |        2 |             2000, 2003 |
+--------+----------+------------------------+
```